# What are different between links methods

Tags: html, relative-path, absolute-path

I am beginner in web designing. Please tell me what are differences between `../aa.css`, `./aa.css` and `/aa.css` links and their meaning in html.

is this effect to URL `www.example.com/aa` and `www.example.com/aa/` deference

Comment: It's like any other file system path. `../` = up one folder. `./` = this folder. `/` = root folder.

Comment: is there any other type of methods?

Comment: @JimL is this effect to URL www.example.com/aa and www.example.com/aa/ deference

Answer (score 2):

The ./ and ../ directories it's simple: . is current directory, .. is previous directory (parent directory) And / represent the root directory

**For More understanding with folder/directory:**

Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there

Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there

Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts there (and so on...)

To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep moving forward

Hope so it would be helpful !

Answer (score -1):

You must use user friendly url for seo.
In user friendly seo, you must use slash before assets such as img css links etc

You should use /aa.css versus others.